# Blazor Component Property Setter Async

Tags: blazor

In blazor component EventCallbacks are used to communicate changed data back to parent. It's often convienient to send update in property setter method.
However, this isn't a good idea because invocation is async and should be awaited (otherwise exceptions in callback method aren't thrown) and it's not possible to await in property setter.

Why does [setter for Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.InputBase.CurrentValue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/8cf98856bb96c7aad8373ae5b1fa6e7f021f649e/src/Components/Web/src/Forms/InputBase.cs#L80) call InvokeAsync?